# Associated model is not saving data when page is refreshed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Rails 3.1 RC4**

I have a 1:1 association between **User** and **Profile**.
When I submit the new profile form, the data I've entered is displayed just fine (see screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjTQe.png), but when I refresh it the data is instantly wiped.

Could anyone tell me what is causing this?

Here's the submit form:
`<%= form_for([@user, @user.build_profile]) do |f| %>`
        `<div class="field">`
            `<%= f.label :first_name %><br />`
            `<%= f.text_field :first_name %>`
        `</div>`
        `<div class="field">`
            `<%= f.label :last_name %><br />`
            `<%= f.text_field :last_name %>`
        `</div>`
        `<div class="field">`
            `<%= f.label :picture %><br />`
            `<%= f.text_field :picture %>`
        `</div>`
        `<div class="field">`
            `<%= f.radio_button(:sex, "male") %>`
            `<%= f.label(:sex, "Male") %>`
            `<%= f.radio_button(:sex, "female") %>`
            `<%= f.label(:sex, "Female") %>`
        `</div>`
        `<div class="actions">`
            `<%= f.submit %>`
        `</div>`
    `<% end %>`

Here's the users_controller: https://github.com/imjp/SuperModel/blob/master/app/controllers/users_controller.rb
Here's the profiles_controller: https://github.com/imjp/SuperModel/blob/master/app/controllers/profiles_controller.rb

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I agree with your approach. Why don't you do something like this:

In models/user.rb:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
```

In controllers/users_controller.rb:

```
def new
  @user = User.new
  @user.build_profile
end
```

In views/users/_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
  <%= f.fields_for :profile do |pf| %>
    <%= pf.text_field :some_profile_field %>
  <% end -%>
<%- end -%>
```

This isn't copied or tested, but it should work. On saving your user, the profile fields are sent along and validated with the user fields and are re-rendered when rendering the form again after a save error. This way you will keep full control over your form and its contents with minimal effort.

Comment: Wouldn't the forms for profile and user be submitted by 1 submit button then? I don't want that as I plan to add 2 more models under user once I get this to work. Also, I would need the users to edit the forms on their own instead of everything at once.