# submitted data vanishes after page refresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Associated model is not saving data when page is refreshed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6781372/associated-model-is-not-saving-data-when-page-is-refreshed)

I have a 1:1 association between **User** and **Profile**.
When I submit the new profile form, the data I've entered is displayed just fine (see screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygA2y.png), but when I refresh it the data is instantly wiped.

Could anyone tell me what is causing this?

Here's the submit form:

> <%= form_for([@user, @user.build_profile]) do |f| %>
>    
>        `<div
>   class="field">`
>            `<%= f.label :first_name %><br />`
>           `<%=
>   f.text_field :first_name %>`
>       `</div>`
>         `<div
>   class="field">`
>            `<%= f.label :last_name %><br />`
>            `<%=
>   f.text_field :last_name %>`
>        `</div>`
>         `<div
>   class="field">`
>            `<%= f.label :picture %><br />`
>              `<%=
>   f.text_field :picture %>`
>          `</div>`
>         `<div class="field">`
>   
>              `<%= f.radio_button(:sex, "male") %>`
>            `<%=
>   f.label(:sex, "Male") %>`
>              `<%= f.radio_button(:sex, "female")
>   %>`
>            `<%= f.label(:sex, "Female") %>`
>         `</div>`
>         `<div
>   class="actions">`
>              `<%= f.submit %>`
>        `</div>`
>    `<%
>   end %>`

Here's the users_controller: https://github.com/imjp/SuperModel/blob/master/app/controllers/users_controller.rb
Here's the profiles_controller: https://github.com/imjp/SuperModel/blob/master/app/controllers/profiles_controller.rb

Comment: Why are you passing 2 users as url segments to your `form_for`?

Comment: I have no idea man... it's how they did it in the getting started tutorial of guides.rubyonrails.org and it works there (even though that was a one to many relationship). I'm still very news to rails and I don't really understand everything.. they didn't explain why they did that either

Comment: Any idea?? Submitted this post 3 times already in the past week hoping for someone to help me out.. it's not hard if you know rails :(

Comment: You asked [this same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6781372) yesterday.  **Don't do that.**  It's a huge waste of people's time.

Comment: Well, nobody was helping me out so it obviously wasn't wasting anybody's time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, it's failing because:

- passing `@user.build_profile` instantiates a new profile each time.
- sidenote but I highly recommend you create the profile just after the user is created.

[Look at my commit on your forked repository](https://github.com/apneadiving/SuperModel/commit/04d8138f23218e5343ff53a1cb447fc3d01763d2).

Comment: Hey thanks for the commit man! Here's the error I'm getting now though: http://i.imgur.com/GIJCB.png

Comment: OK, weird, should be a matter of ruby version replace with `form_for([@user, @profile])`

Comment: Nice job man! It works now :) I'm so happy haha